# mod_rewrite rewriting all folders

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to create clean links. I've gotten it to take my urls from this:

http://www.example.com/index.php?LTKeywords=long-tail-keyword

to

http://www.example.com/long-tail-keyword/

Which is exactly what I want. The code I used is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index2.php?LTKeywords=$1
```

One Problem.

It now redirects all of my folders, so anything in my `/images/` or `/css/` folders will not show up. Is there a way to stop it from rewriting specific folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). You can prefix with `!` to specify must-not-match:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
```

for example.

You may also just want to exclude directories which actually exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
```

Finally, you could also put your static content on a different hostname (virtualhost), avoiding your rewrite rules all together.

You could also add some more RewriteRules to match your CSS, etc. and make them not actually change anything (rewrite /css to /css) but specify the L (last) flag, so the other rules wouldn't run.

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I did what you suggested I got a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @user1086352: Sorry, I first posted that with a syntax error, which I *think* I've fixed now. If you still get a 500, check your Apache error log, see if there are details there.

Comment: It worked! Thank You! When I used the first suggestion (and removed the '^') it worked perfectly. I couldn't get the second one to work, but I'm not that concerned with it.

Thanks Again!!